# A web project I worked on is being closed down, does anyone have suggestions on how to share the code and story of its development?

Tags: web-apps

I have worked as the lead dev on a web app aimed at the educational sector for the last 10 years. Unfortunately, the time has come for the project to be closed down, primarily due to time constraints and costs. It was a useful system back in the day, but would require quite a lot of work to modernise.

What I'm wondering is, is there any way to share the story of its development, and to allow others to view the code? We've thought about uploading the whole thing to a Github repo, but that seems very impersonal. Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do with old projects/apps? Thanks.

Comment: Publishing the version control history indeed seems to be the right thing to do. Could you clarify what you would like to see in addition to the changesets to make it more personal?

Comment: Most authors include a README.md on github with as much or as little history as they want.  Although I have not tested the limits, so there might be a limit.

Comment: Please could you share the link to the project? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think this is too related to "software recommendation". It's more like "best software practices". This part of StackExchange - [SoftwareEngineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) - seems like a much better place to ask since it lists "software development methods and practices".

But to answer - GitHub is indeed a good place that may help some people who are looking for similar code and it's the biggest platform for code sharing. To make it more "personal", you could e.g. record a YouTube video on top, where you would explain the software and its history from user's rather than coder's perspective.